# How to loop and read content from a range of memory address

Tags: c, memory-address

I'm new to C and I would like to read content from range of memory address

Assume that I have following range of address : 0x00065580 - 0x000655c0

this range get from command :

```
 $ cat /proc/a_process_pid/maps | grep heap
 00065580-000655c0 ...........heap
```

( Please see the hex dump image from above range )

[image]

I tried to using loop but have no luck ,( just like the think of a Java dev )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define START_ADDR 0x00065580 
#define END_ADDR 0x000655c0
int main(){
   char *start = START_ADDR ;
   char *end = END_ADDR;
   for( char *i=start ; i <= end ; i++ ){
        printf("%s",i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

It generate  error :

```
root@localhost:~# ./test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please tell me what am I wrong and what I need to learn about ?

Comment: Is test the name of your source code file? You might be compiling your executable ,

Comment: Sorry , Im run program in wrong way ,I edit the error ,just simple " Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: `printf("%s",*i);`  isn't it?

Comment: Where did you get those address values? What makes you believe that those addresses actually contain valid memory in your process memory space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read content of memory address 0xfeafe000 in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000017/how-to-read-content-of-memory-address-0xfeafe000-in-c)

Comment: I get from gdb dump , assume that I have "A" process run, I using command ` cat /proc/A's_pid/maps | grep heap` to get heap memory  arrange address of process. And dump this range using gdb

Comment: Sure, but process "A" has a completely different memory layout from *your* process. You can't directly read from process "A" memory.

Comment: but why gdb can dump it ? Is gdb is no relate to A, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

Modern operating systems use [*virtual memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory): the memory addresses that a process sees are different from the physical addresses, and programs normally can't touch the memory that is owned by another process. You appear to be looking at a memory dump from one particular process, but address `0x00065580` does in reality correspond to a different physical address, e.g. `0x00123456`. And inside your own program, address `0x00065580` will correspond to another physical address, e.g. `0x00589263`. The operating system will ensure that none of the physical addresses that are used by the other program will be accessible from yours.

If your process is running as root, you can [use system calls to indirectly access other processes' memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920691/626853).

Comment: Thanks Aasmund ,I known program is using virtual memory , I just want to read from it 。Could I read from virtual memory ？

Comment: Perhaps a brief bit of history of the change from **real mode** computing to **protected mode** computing would help firm up the understanding.

Comment: @Ryo: The point is that a process (a running program) can only read from _its own_ virtual memory, not from another process' virtual memory. And the operating system won't let your process access the physical memory that another process' virtual memory is mapped to (unless your processes specifically request shared memory).

Comment: The process I need to read memory from is a GT.M database process , it using shared memory segment http://tinco.pair.com/bhaskar/gtm/doc/books/ao/UNIX_manual/apas01.htm  .Do I have any chance ?

Comment: @Ryo: The link is broken.

Comment: Thanks ,It should be : tinco.pair.com/bhaskar/gtm/doc/books/ao/UNIX_manual/apas01.html

Comment: @Ryo: That page mentions both shared memory segments being created by [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [`shmat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmat.2.html). In both cases, the addresses of the shared memory segment will likely be different in the two processes, and you can't access it based on memory address. For `mmap`, you need to specify a file descriptor for the same file that the running program used for its memory mapping; for `shmat`, you need the identifier for that particular shared-memory segment.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a C++ program which will shed some light on how to print addresses (or data) for particular memory locations.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int* arr = new int[10];
    int *start = NULL;
    int *end = NULL;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        arr[i] = i+1;
    start = arr;
    end = &arr[9];
    for(int *start=arr;start<end;start++)
        cout<<"  "<<start;
    cout<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I do not see any issue in your pasted code. But the problem is the START and END, i.e. the location of addresses you are using in your program. These locations does not contain any valid memory for that process hence you are forcefully asking to read data from some junk memory space resulting in SEGFAULT. Hope this helps.

Comment: There are two issues with your answer: first, it's C++ code and the OP has tagged C, not C++. Second: there is indeed an issue with the OP's code: he is trying to print the contents of the pointer as if they were a string.

Comment: It mean that I only can read from memory address using by my program and can not access memory of another process ?

Comment: @Ryo Your program will run in user mode, and definitely you can not access memory of some other process. Memory Access limit for a process is it's own allocated memory. You can access a particular memory if you are sure about that it's a valid memory address for your process.  unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*) 0xffef8016, i repeat it's possible if 0xffef8016 is a valid memory address for your process.

Comment: I see that Linux have ptrace() function for trace another process , Is this possible to using in my case ?

Comment: I tried with ptrace ,but it sleep another process during tracing ,Its not suit in my case